# comparing multiple files to get common values

Tags: python, file

I am trying to compare 1100 files in a directory. I want to compare the values in the "first col" of each file after `line.split()` and write output-file with the common values (as first col) and the name of the files from where I come from (as next common where this value is present), like following:

```
common-value    file-name-1   file-name-2 ..... file-name-n
```

I read all the files with `glob()` function but after that, I am pretty much blank. Can someone suggest a simple solution?

Comment: If its a common value, then it comes from more than one file name. How do you represent that?

Comment: Yes, I already edited my initial question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict` whose keys are "first col" items and values are a list of files where they are found. As you go through the files, update the dict. This can be accelerated with a few python tricks as noted

```
import collections

# a dictionary that autocreates an empty list as value for each new key
common = collections.defaultdict(list)

for fn in glob('someglob'):
    with open(fn) as fp:
        # use set to get list of unique column 1 values then iterate to add
        # to common accumulator
        for col1val in set(line.split()[0] for line in fp):
            common[col1val].append(fn)

# rebuild accumulator, discarding col1vals from only 1 file
common = {col1val:files for col1val, files in common.items() if len(files) > 1}

for col1val, files in common.items():
    print(col1val, " ".join(files))
```

Comment: Thanks but in print("col1val", " ".join(files))  "col1val" is with "" that is not correct it must be without "".

Comment: oops, my bad. quote removed.